# What range of dates are permitted in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

What is the maximum and the minimum date that I can use with the `Date` object in Javascript?

Is it possible to represent ancient historical dates (like `January 1, 2,500 B.C.`) or dates that are far into the future (like `October 7, 10,000`)?

If these far-from-present dates can't be represented with the `Date` object, how should I represent them?

Comment: So, what's the point of asking *"If these far-from-present dates can't be represented..."* when you already knew they could be represented? Why pose the question, if you know it's moot? :P

Comment: @user1689607 I don't know, the question just felt incomplete without it.

Comment: Well, it was an interesting question anyway. Good to see JS doesn't suffer the 2038 problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [§15.9.1.1 of the ECMA-262 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.1),

> Time is measured in ECMAScript in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC.
>   ...
>   The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is ... exactly **–100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC.** This gives a range of 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC.

So the earliest date representable with the `Date` object is fairly far beyond known human history:

```
new Date(-8640000000000000).toUTCString()
// Tue, 20 Apr 271,822 B.C. 00:00:00 UTC
```

The latest date is sufficient to last beyond [Y10K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem) and even beyond Y100K, but will need to be reworked a few hundred years before Y276K.

```
new Date(8640000000000000).toUTCString()
// Sat, 13 Sep 275,760 00:00:00 UTC
```

Any date outside of this range will return `Invalid Date`.

```
new Date(8640000000000001)   // Invalid Date
new Date(-8640000000000001)  // Invalid Date
```

---

In short, the JavaScript `Date` type will be **sufficient for measuring time to millisecond precision within approximately 285,616 years before or after January 1, 1970**. The dates posted in the question are very comfortably inside of this range.

Comment: I believe the date for the past has a typo. This is what I get



new Date(-8640000000000000).toUTCString() = 'Tue, 20 Apr -271821 00:00:00 GMT'

Comment: @Rohit Notice the `1` at the end. `new Date(-8640000000000001)` is `Invalid Date`, while `new Date(-8640000000000000)` is the date you got, the earliest valid date.